Gradle 8.3.2 Upgrade gives Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'
After Upgrading my android studio and Updating my JDK from 11 to 17
Also Upgraded Gradle from 7.4.2 to 8.3.2
I am having issues to create release build apk
./gradlew assembleRelease fails with the R8 issue
The issue I am getting is something like this
Execution failed for task ':stream:minifyPreprodReleaseWithR8'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
Compilation failed to complete

I am also seeing something like this

Task :stream:minifyPreprodReleaseWithR8 FAILED
ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in /Users/sthakkar/Desktop/GlobalTV/global-tv-android/stream/build/outputs/mapping/preprodRelease/missing_rules.txt.
ERROR: R8: Missing class java.beans.ConstructorProperties (referenced from: void com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl.() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class java.beans.Transient (referenced from: void com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl.() and 1 other context)
Missing class javax.xml.stream.Location (referenced from: net.sf.saxon.s9api.Location net.sf.saxon.pull.StaxBridge.getSourceLocator() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter (referenced from: net.sf.saxon.event.Receiver net.sf.saxon.stax.StAXResultHandlerImpl.getReceiver(javax.xml.transform.Result, java.util.Properties))
Missing class javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException (referenced from: void net.sf.saxon.pull.StaxBridge.close() and 10 other contexts)
Missing class javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader (referenced from: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader net.sf.saxon.pull.StaxBridge.reader and 9 other contexts)
Missing class javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter (referenced from: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter net.sf.saxon.stax.ReceiverToXMLStreamWriter.writer and 10 other contexts)
Missing class javax.xml.stream.events.EntityDeclaration (referenced from: java.util.List net.sf.saxon.pull.StaxBridge.getUnparsedEntities())
Missing class javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXResult (referenced from: net.sf.saxon.event.Receiver net.sf.saxon.lib.SerializerFactory.getReceiverForNonSerializedResult(javax.xml.transform.Result, java.util.Properties, net.sf.saxon.event.PipelineConfiguration) and 1 other context)
Missing class javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource (referenced from: javax.xml.transform.Source net.sf.saxon.Configuration.resolveSource(javax.xml.transform.Source, net.sf.saxon.Configuration) and 1 other context)

I tried adding enableR8 in gradle.properties but its depricated
I tried Invalidate/Cache
I also made sure I was using JDK 17 and also updated it in build.gradle

You probably need to add more specific error stacktraces instead of "R8Task$R8Runnable Compilation failed to complete". Currently what you posted is just a general error mentioned the error is regarding R8. You can try different Gradle log level to find out more relative information:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html

Build successfully after add this to proguard-rules.pro
-dontwarn java.beans.ConstructorProperties
-dontwarn java.beans.Transient

